# Zoom out image in center using JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to animate the image and keep it exactly in the center of the currently opened window.
I have tried the following, but it is not working please suggest how to improve the code to get it working.

```
   // get image dimensions
   var h = $(this).height();
   var w = $(this).width();

    //get div dimensions
    var div_h =$('#imgContainer').height();
    var div_w =$('#imgContainer').width();

    var  pY = Math.round((div_h - h) / 2) + 'px';
    var  pX = Math.round((div_w - w) / 2) + 'px';

    $(this).animate({
        opacity:"1", 
        top: pY+"px",
        left: pX+"px",
        zoom: '500%'
    }, 'medium')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the rest of your markup.
Your code works for me this way:

([**check the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/FEQxA/))

HTML:

```
<div id="imgContainer">
<img src="your-image.jpg">
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #imgContainer {
    width:100%; height:100%;
}
#imgContainer > img {
    position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
    margin:auto;
    width:200px;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#imgContainer > img').on('click',function(){
   var h = $(this).height();
   var w = $(this).width();

    //get div dimensions
    var div_h =$('#imgContainer').height();
    var div_w =$('#imgContainer').width();

    var  pY = Math.round((div_h - h) / 2) + 'px';
    var  pX = Math.round((div_w - w) / 2) + 'px';

    $(this).animate({
        opacity:"1", 
        zoom: '500%'
    }, 1000)

});
```

Comment: Your solution doesnt work in firefox.. using firefox 20.* .. looks like zoom property is not supported by firefox.

Comment: What about zooming back to original size? That would be dandy.

Comment: @Giona that works! Thank you very much. I love the image you used too haha. I would assume I would need to use a higher resolution image than a thumbnail so as not to loose quality when the size increases by 500%.

Comment: yup @JustJohn , o maybe just change the src attribute of the img onclick...it really depends on what you need this script for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery zoom plugin](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom). Following is the usage example:

```
// Example:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.photo').zoom({url: 'photo-big.jpg'});
});

// Using ColorBox with Zoom
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.photo').zoom({
        url: 'photo-big.jpg', 
        callback: function(){
            $(this).colorbox({href: this.src});
        }
    });
});
```