# jQuery slideToggle (Toggle from middle point)

Tags: jquery, css, animation, slidetoggle

I am using `slideToggle();` method, it's working, I just want to slide in and out from middle point of image not slideup to left corner. 
I also don't want zoomIn or zoomOut event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('img').stop().slideToggle(5000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default">My Button</button>
<br><br><br>
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://news.stanford.edu/news/2012/september/images/online_keyboard_news.jpg">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kararbarcha/qv9Ltudh/13/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777861/zoom-out-image-in-center-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to using jQuery animations, what you are looking for (assuming I understand what you are explaining) can be accomplished with a slight change to your DOM structure and adding a few lines of css.

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementById("toggle-button");
const imageContainer = document.getElementById("image-container");

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    imageContainer.classList.toggle("show");
});
```

```css
button {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
}

/* Create a wrapper element that matches the image size */
/* and set it to the desired image reveal size */

.wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Add the image container element and set it to the center of the wrapper */ 
/* set the width and height to 0 so the image isn't visible */

.image {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: url(http://news.stanford.edu/news/2012/september/images/online_keyboard_news.jpg)
    no-repeat center center;
    transition-duration: 1000ms;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 1, 1);
}

/* When we want to show the image animate the width and height */
/* to fit the container as well as adjust the margin to keep it centered */

.image.show {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -300px; /* set to half of the containing elements width */
    margin-top: -200px; /* set half of the containing elements height */
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.5, 1);
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle-button">
  Toggle Image
</button>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image show" id="image-container"></div>
</div>
```

I created a quick example of how it could work with css only using javascript to toggle a class on the image element.

Comments in the css describe how this was accomplished.

Comment: Thank you @Curt, Your code result is fine and same like what i want but i am using image in **html tag** not in css as a background image. Because i am using dynamic image in html.

Comment: How about something like [this](https://codepen.io/curthusting/pen/RxZZza/)? Not exactly the same as the original, but it is similar...and I'm sure with a little more time and effort the same as the original can be achieved.

Comment: Thanks again, not enough! its working fine but **Toggle IN and OUT point**  is not in middle point of image... Now  **Toggle IN and OUT point** is Horizontally Middle but not in Vertically. Thanks again i am also trying to solve it.

Comment: you should be able to make it center horizontally by adding a few lines of css...add this property to `.wrapper` `margin: 200px auto;` and add this property to `.wrapper.show` `margin: 0 auto; ` that should fix it. That will get the necessary size & spacing required to start the toggle in the center of the image I updated my [pen](https://codepen.io/curthusting/pen/RxZZza) to reflect the changes

Comment: Thank you @Curt almost done, Just one thing! is it possible with auto height and width?? Actually i want to use Toggle for all size of images not with fixed height and width. image and .wrapper.show height and width must be auto.

Comment: @llyas - that is code I wrote for this question ;), Karar - I will take a look and see what I can come up with for the variable width & height, I am thinking we can read the image dimensions with javascript and use that info...we'll see what I can do

Comment: @KararBarcha Here's a working demo with dynamic image sizes https://codepen.io/curthusting/pen/YYLNxm?editors=0010

Comment: Perfect. It working very well... thank you so much @Curt

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the `img` with a `div`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function() {
    $('#image_wrapper').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-default">My Button</button>
<br><br><br>
<div id="image_wrapper">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://news.stanford.edu/news/2012/september/images/online_keyboard_news.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Wrong Answer! your code's result looks like up and down (collapse up and expend down) but i want expend in and out middle point of image. same result like @Curt in very next Answer but image must be in HTML TAG not in CSS as background image.